# Double for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var
startx = 0,
starty = 0,
endx = 12,
endy = 100;

for(startx;startx <= endx; startx+=1){
        for(starty; starty <= endy; starty+=1){
            console.log(startx, endx, starty, endy);
     }
}
```

Expected output:

```
0, 12, 0, 100
0, 12, 1, 100
0, 12, 2, 100
...
0, 12, 100, 100
1, 12, 0, 100
1, 12, 1, 100
...
12, 12, 100, 100
;EOO
```

Output on Chrome 39+

```
0, 12, 0, 100
0, 12, 1, 100
0, 12, 2, 100
...
0, 12, 100, 100
```

So the problem is the first for loop does not iterate over startx variable.

Could you tell me why it does not iterate?

Comment: MS Edge does the same.
Actual Firefox too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That was a fun puzzle. It took me a few times before i caught it.

The reason is that `starty` is not reset after the first iteration and therefore the second for loop will only run once since the condition will always go false.

You want:

```
var startx = 0,
    starty = 0,
    endx = 12,
    endy = 100;

for (; startx <= endx; startx++) {
    for (starty = 0; starty <= endy; starty++) {
        console.log(startx, endx, starty, endy);
    }
}
```

I also simplified `startx+=1` to `startx++`, same goes for `starty`.

I will also suggest to get into the habit of writing each `var` statement on it's own:

```
var a;
var b;
```

This makes it easier to stop on when debugging. Try stepping into `def()` without stepping into `abc()`.

```
var a = abc(),
    b = def();
```

---

How is a for loop broken down:

The for loop is broken down into 3 parts:

```
for(initial; condition; after)
```

`initial` is called before the loop, can safely be omitted.
`condition` is called just before running the code in the loop, will always be true if omitted
`after` is called after the code in the loop same as writing:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10;) {
  // code
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! (the += is my own convention - it is more clear for me :) )

Comment: How comes you omit the first parameter of the for loops? I've never seen that before. Does it default to zero?

Comment: It is optional, it is just ancient thing after C, I belive

Comment: @DavidJones Updated the answer for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var startx = 0,
starty = 0, 
endx = 12, 
endy = 100; 
for(startx;startx <= endx; startx++){
  for(starty; starty <= endy; starty++){ 
   console.log(startx, endx, starty, endy); 
 } }
```

Here your second `for loop` execute *100 times* because your condition is `starty <= endy` and *endy assing the value of 100 .* when startx is 0. After finishing the execution of second for loop the startx increment to 1 and again the processed is goes on till it gain the value of 12 . browser's shows the complete results you can console it and scroll down. You will get your desired out put. Hope it useful for you.